# Why my pleated skirt wiggle in cloth simulate

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image]
[image]
it seems like that such structure dosen't work in blender 
How can I optimizate it?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the Cloth quality steps and collision/self collision quality (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YTpp.png)? Cloth works best with consistently sized quads so you may need to retopologise your mesh.

Comment: Yes,I have tried both the skirt face and the quality steps.The skirt is simulated correctly in MD,but the wrong style in blender

Comment: Applied Scale on both the model and the cloth mesh?

Comment: It improve pretty much after I decreased the mass,apply scale,increased the subdivision and the quality of Self-Collision like [ your another answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102861/self-collision-not-work-well).<br/>But I still dont know what cause the wiggle if you still have spare time.[here is my blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nEoVLzLtPWF1ngzJFChWWZM4ZQm5cUou/view?usp=sharing).Thanks a lot .

Comment: I believe the problem is likely due to the interactions with the layers of cloth, compounded with how coarsely the mesh is subdivided - since the cloth simulation is dependent on edge length, the folded layers are becoming overlapped. Try going into Edit mode, select all, click Subdivide twice, then re-run. Unfortunately my system isn't powerful enough to run this simulation effectively - it was taking minutes per frame to simulate so not practical for me to run it. Also, the scaling is outside realistic limits - rescale it to be about 1BU high (assume 1BU=1m) and apply scale. see if helps.

Comment: appreciate it,I nearly solve my problem,actually just one subdivide can be great effect.Thanks a lot for your help.BTW, one frame per second is too slow....<br/>I'm still confused why  scale affects the simulation result,it is strange right?

Comment: That’s great that you’re nearly there. Once you’re ready it would be good if yoo could add an answer so others can benefit from your experience. The overall scale will certainly have an effect on gravity - since it’s around 9.81 BU/s/s - so it’s always best to size things based on their size in the real world. Scale can also affect rounding errors so extremes are best avoided. I’ve found Soft Body to be more adjustable for cloth so sometimes that can cope in situations where cloth cannot.

Comment: I'm new to this community,I never thought I can be helped so much,you are so good.Thank you

Comment: If you issue was not address then share your blend file here

Answer (score 0):

You can try scaling it up to 10. If it still persists you can scale it again, but remember that by scaling it too much you have to adjust your camera settings, but this improves the render time.